# Scraping subreddit top posts of all time using requests is returning the wrong result

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, reddit

I would like to scrape a subreddit for their top posts of **all time**. I know there is a `PRAW` module that may work better, but I would prefer to scrape using `requests` only for now.

```
import requests

url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/shittysuperpowers/top/?t=all.html"
headers = {"User-agent": "bot_0.1"}
res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

`res.status_code` returned a 200, and the scrape was successful. But closer inspection of `res.text` revealed that the data html scraped is not from the desired page. In fact, what was scraped were from the top posts **today** rather than of all time, or from this url `https://www.reddit.com/r/shittysuperpowers/top/?t=day.html`. Is there any reason why I am unable to scrape the top posts of all time? I have tried this with other subreddits too and they all run into the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `.json` modifier before the queries to get the data in json format.

```py
import requests
url = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/shittysuperpowers/top/.json?sort=top&t=all'
resp = requests.get(url, headers = {'User-agent': 'bot_0.1'})
if resp.ok:
    data = resp.json()
```

The `.json` modifier also works in browser.